# reduced system: primal-dual interior point method for nonconvex constrained problem

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization, nonlinear-programming, nonconvex

When solving a reduced KKT system of a nonlinear (and nonconvex) constrained program after eliminating slack and dual variables, how do we actually take the next step in a primal-dual method?

For example, following notation from [NW](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387303031), if the original nonlinear system is like (19.12)
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla_{xx}^2 L & 0 & A_E(x)^T & A_I(x)^T \\
0 & \Sigma & 0 & -I \\
A_E(x) & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
A_I(x) & -I & 0 & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p_x \\ p_s \\ -p_y \\ -p_z
\end{bmatrix}
= 
-\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla f(x) - A_E(x)^Ty - A_I(x)^T z \\ z - \mu S^{-1}e \\ c_E(x) \\ c_I(x) - s
\end{bmatrix},
\end{align}

then I see how a solution gives us a way to update $x,s,y,z$. However, if we solve a reduced system of the form

\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\nabla_{xx}^2 L + A_I(x)^T\Sigma A_I(x) & A_E(x)^T \\
A_E(x) & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p_x \\ -p_y
\end{bmatrix}
=
\text{?}
\end{align}

then (1) what is the RHS; and (2) how do we update $s,z$?

---

**EDIT:** Can I have some help on the details for how we eliminate variables in moving from the larger system to the smaller system?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have $p_x,p_y$, you can use the second and fourth of the block system you show in your question to compute the updates $p_s,p_z$. They satisfy the equations
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}
\Sigma & -I \\
-I & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
p_s \\ -p_z
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
z - \mu S^{-1}e \\ c_I(x) - s - A_I(x)p_x
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks! And to confirm, I can use the same approach for calculating step size as if I solved the full system outright? Btw -- I made a typo on the last line of my large system, so I believe the lower left $I$ of your program should be $-I$?

Comment: Yes, I had already wondered about the minus sign. I fixed it.

Comment: And yes, once you have all of the updates $p_\ast$ computed as above, you can do a linear search.

Comment: Thanks -- as a follow up, when I computed $p^*$ under the full and reduced systems of my original formulation (using the $\Sigma, -I...$ submatrix to get $p^*_s, p^*_y$), I was getting different results (this was for $dim(x) = 10$ so I don't think numerical issues were present). I believe the RHS is wrong for my reduced system?

Comment: Isn't the reduced system just some Schur complement? You'll have to go through the derivation again.